# Write a OGG file from a InputStream

Tags: java, file, inputstream, ogg, icecast

Im trying to write a local OGG file from a icecast mount point with ogg data. I make the connection with URL, get the InputStream and capture this in a AudioInpustStream that support OGG format through vorbisspi, i can play this in the dataline and i can write data on a ogg file but i cant play this file on vlc player, i try with this code and i dont have errors in the compilation.

[Click here to data line example](http://odoepner.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/play-mp3-or-ogg-using-javax-sound-sampled-mp3spi-vorbisspi/)

CODE.

```
public class AppSave {

private URL url;
private URLConnection urlconection;
private InputStream inputStream;
private AudioInputStream aisin;
private File file;

public AppSave() {
    url = null;
    urlconection = null;
    inputStream = null;
    aisin = null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, IOException {
    final AppSave player = new AppSave();
    player.save("http://192.168.0.21/virtual.ogg");//Mount point
}

public void save(String mountpoint) throws LineUnavailableException, IOException {

    try {
        url = new URL(mountpoint); //URL icecast mount point
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.err.println("URL Malformed " + mountpoint);
    }

    try {
        urlconection = url.openConnection();//open connexion with URL
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Connexion unrealized");
    }

    try {
        inputStream = urlconection.getInputStream();//get raw data
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("InputStream without data");
    }

    try {
        try {
            aisin = getAudioInputStream(inputStream);//prepare data for playback
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Unsupported format");
        }

        final AudioFormat outFormat = getOutFormat(aisin.getFormat());//obtain format
        String pathfile = "/home/stream/myfile.ogg";//output file path
        File file = createfile(pathfile);
        savestream(getAudioInputStream(outFormat, aisin), file);

    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

private AudioFormat getOutFormat(AudioFormat inFormat) {//obtain format
    final int ch = inFormat.getChannels();
    final float rate = inFormat.getSampleRate();
    return new AudioFormat(PCM_SIGNED, rate, 16, ch, ch * 2, rate, false);
}

private File createfile(String pathfile) throws IOException {//create and return the output file
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter(pathfile);
    pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);
    File file = new File(pathfile);
    return file;
}

private void savestream(AudioInputStream in, File outfile) throws IOException {//save stream
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (int n = 0; n != -1; n = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    out.close();
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>SaveOGG</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SaveOGG</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>tritonus-share</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.7-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mp3spi</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>vorbisspi</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3-1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. People are much less likely to hep you if you ask them to "check this code for me" ... can you instead tell us what you've tried to make it work? what the error looks like? does it give you an error messages? can you please edit your question and tell us what that error is (do not answer in the comments - re-edit your question).give us a tad more info for us to go please? :)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your advice, i dont see any errors in the compilation, the code run fine with the data line(you can see the example in the link on my questions) and the ogg local file grows increasingly but i cant play this.

Comment: There will be an error somewhere - usually spit out by the player that tries to play it (to say why it is unplayable).